# Is there unique information or other reasons a Windows event 'Message' should not be discarded?

Tags: windows, logging, windows-event-log

Perhaps showing my ignorance, but is there any reason to keep the `Message` from a Windows event, when ingesting into a log system?

Is it the case that these are composed of data from other attributes, for localization/readability, and could be discarded without losing important data?

I don't know if this is the right spot to read, but [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wes/defining-events) seems to point to that case?

Scope:

Only care about Microsoft-y events.  If some random person could in theory write their own event with unique data in the message field via PowerShell or some other ad hoc means, I don't care about that

Context:

Ingesting into a logging system, and the `message` field bloats storage significantly.  Generally, details about the meaning of an event is well documented , or could be explored on a local system when building tooling to expose the data once it ships to the log system, sans `message`

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the message field, at least, for pre-defined event schema, can be discarded.

Thanks to josh_p for pointing to [this blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ashleymcglone/2013/08/28/powershell-get-winevent-xml-madness-getting-details-from-event-logs/)

An example showing how the Message field is composed for a particular event id:

```perl
( Get-WinEvent -ListProvider Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy ).Events |
 Where-Object {$_.Id -eq 5314}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the IT security field, it may be interesting to disable the collection of the "Message" part while collecting events into a SIEM, . This will reduce the size of the transmitted data and will also reduce the load of the collector server.

When using the Windows Event Collector (WEC) feaure, it is possible to disable the collection of the "Message" by switching from "**RenderedText**" (so with the full "Message") to the optimized mode "**Events**" (without the “Message”) in the subscription settings. This is shown in the image below in "ContentFormat".

[image]

Comment: Yep!  For what it's worth, we went from 4.6 million documents in 7.5GB, to 4.7 million documents in 4.3 GB.  Unscientific single day comparison with `message` stripped from all events, but a pretty decent savings.

We'll likely strip them only from specific high-volume events where they don't add value going forward.